# nginx can't proxy_pass request using map cookie

Tags: cookies, nginx, abtest

I want to use cookie to indicate which backend server to perform the request. here is my configuration:

```
upstream backend_prod   {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
upstream backend_abenv   {
    server 127.0.0.1:9090;
}
map $COOKIE_backend $gated {
    default prod;
    eexxpptt abenv;
}
server {
    listen       8888;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        index  index.jsp index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://backend_$gated;
    }
}
```

I have set cookie backend:eexxpptt. 
But I got a weird URL `http://backend_prod` when I visit `http://localhost:8888` in chrome. And do not reach the 8080 or 9090 server.

Any advice?

Comment: nginx 1.6.0_1 , 
OS X 10.9.4